# Can I "block" a question?

Tags: discussion

I just asked a question on the main site, but I think I've figured out the answer and no-one has yet (while I am writing this) commented or answered on it.

Is there a way for me to "block" the question, so it is live but no-one can see it and so I can then edit it into a different question at a later date and this doesn't waste one of my $6$ a day questions?

Comment: you have that many quesitons to ask? :P

Comment: @Lost1 Not all the time, but on certain topics, sometimes I do. Also, it clogs up the website having useless empty questions

Comment: Here is a suggestion: ask only 5 (other) questions on the day of the mistake.

Comment: I think that if you figure out an answer to your question, the correct thing to do is write it down and post it as an answer.

Comment: Don't do anything and wait: you'll get the tumbleweed badge as a reward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you just delete the question, edit it, then undelete it?

Comment: Didn't know you can undelete questions

Comment: You can undelete them if you can find them again.  If you leave the page and forget the URL, you can't find the deleted question again.  If you stay on the same page, you can undelete it.

Comment: Deleted questions cannot be edited now. in a few days ago even after refreshing the deleted question disappeared.

Comment: @CutieKrait That shouldn't be a problem for the $5$ question limit, which was OP's concern.  In that timeframe one can simply ask the modified question as a new question.